# can't write a file properly using php

Tags: php, html

```
<?php
$CreateFile = fopen("allinfo.html","a") or die("unable to create file");
                        $up = "<div class="infofilediv">";
                        $fwrite($CreateFile,$up);
                        $fclose($CreateFile);
?>
```

When I am creating this html file I am not able to write "infofilediv" with double quotation marks. How am I able to escape these characters?

Comment: You have double quotes inside your double-quoted string. You should be getting a PHP parse error, which would help you recognize the issue.

Comment: Escape the quotes $up = "<div class=\"infofilediv\">";

Comment: you're not escaping the `"`. should be `$up = "<div class=\"infofilediv\">";`

Comment: Or just use single quotes in one of those places.

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: fwrite in C:\xampp\htdocs\Mess\result.php on line 80
Now what can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape the double-quotes around `infofilediv` and $ before function:

```
$CreateFile = fopen("allinfo.html","a") or die("unable to create file");
                $up = "<div class=\"infofilediv\">";
                fwrite($CreateFile,$up);
                fclose($CreateFile);
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit, @mohade; clearly an oversight while doing my copy/paste >.<

Answer (score 2):

you have two problem  **first with double-quotes here**:

```
$up = "<div class="infofilediv">";
```

you can solve it by two ways :

1) use double-quotes first time and single-quotes second vise versa  like this :

```
$up = "<div class='infofilediv'>";
```

2) escape double-quotes in second time like this :

```
$up = "<div class=\"infofilediv\">";
```

**second with $ before function**

```
$fwrite($CreateFile,$up);
$fclose($CreateFile);
```

replace with

```
 fwrite($CreateFile,$up);
 fclose($CreateFile);
```

$ use with variables

```
$hello="hello world";
```

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: fwrite in C:\xampp\htdocs\Mess\result.php on line 80

Now what? :(

Comment: you cant use $ with function like fwrite, $ use just with variables like this $v="hello world";